# Android - Displaying the Wrong Info for my App

Tags: java, android, android-studio, web-scraping, jsoup

I am scraping data from a local HTML page in Android Studio and instead of the right info being scraped all that its displaying "text_view". Anyone know how to display the data i have scraped? Below is a the main piece of code.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
/*    try {

        File input = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Mobile Newest\\JSoup\\app\\src\\main\\assets\\filename.html");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
        Elements tableElements = doc.select("td");
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        for (Element td : tableElements) {
            textView.setText(td.text());
           System.out.println(td.text());
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
    try {
        StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder();
        InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("filename.html"));
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
        String str;
        while ((str=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            buf.append(str);
        }
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(buf.toString());
        //other code parts goes next
        Elements tableElements = doc.select("td");
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        for (Element td : tableElements) {
            textView.setText(td.text());
            System.out.println(td.text());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Below is the content_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="text_view1"
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot reach that path C:\Users\user\Desktop\Mobile Newest\JSoup\app\src\main\assets\filename.html on your local machine from android device. Have you tried to debug the code? I guess you should have your IOException fired. You can try to read your asset file like this.

```
try {
        StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder();
        InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("filename.html"));
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
        String str;
        while ((str=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            buf.append(str);
        }
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(buf.toString());
        //other code parts goes next

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: other code parts?    Elements tableElements = doc.select("td");
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            for (Element td : tableElements) {
                textView.setText(td.text());
               System.out.println(td.text());
            } this you mean?

Comment: I meant that problem was in the path of file, so you will not read the file and your text view will not be set. Another thing is only last table element will be set. And System.out.println does not work in android, use Log.d instead to see your parsed elements in Logcat.